# Why was my question deleted? I'm terribly sorry if I did something wrong but I didn't mean anything mean

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37914) was downvoted and deleted. Why? It contained a rude word, yeah, it contained that. And what? Can't I ask about rude word? I suppose any word is equal in the linguistic context. Am I wrong?

Comment: That question is no longer viewable, at least for ordinary users like me, so I cannot possibly provide an answer or opinion as the context is gone.

Comment: See also this meta question: https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/etymology-questions-and-close-votes

Answer (score 1):

It was a bad question according to our standards and it was lacking basic research (the etymology of the given rude word is freely and easily available in the Wiktionary) AND it contains a rude word. It was just asked to pronounce the rude word.

It was deleted by community what means that it collected enough rude flags for automated deletion, it was not a moderator's decision. The deletion is all right, given all circumstances, and there is no need to revise it.

Comment: What's the second sentence mean?

Comment: That it contains a rude word is not relevant. OP is right that any word is equal in this sense. Of course it remains that it lacked basic research, so there is no need to undelete. But it should be clear that there is no ban on asking anything about rude words.