# What steps can I take if my question is closed and deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

I have asked [this question] (https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37822/etymology-of-%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m?). My question has been cloced as language-specific. After that https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/28236/tristan has voted to reopen the question. So, I have been flagging my question repeatedly, but my flags are getting declined, and my question has been deleted by the community. So, what steps can I take?
[Etymology questions and close votes](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/etymology-questions-and-close-votes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question was bad because of lack of prior effort. Since Linguistics.SE is still in beta for all practical purposes, the close reasons are sometimes not an exact match; when voting, users choose the closest match from one of the three available choices.

If your flag gets declined, move on from that post. Repeatedly flagging posts will trigger automated tripwires here, and you will not be able to flag anything anymore. Looking at your profile tells me:

- Not banned from flagging
- Warned when flagging

Comment: But I need to ask a question on the etymology.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask these are some general hints

Comment: And I faced similar situations on another site. https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35317/how-to-say-something-gets-old-fast.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was automatically deleted for reasons explained here: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba. I will not reverse the deletion. Please go through the excellent points made in the answers at [Etymology questions and close votes](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/etymology-questions-and-close-votes). Of particular interest to your deleted question, @jk said "we don't want to build a comprehensive etymological dictionary disguised in Q&A format. An etymology needs to stand for some more general phenomenon to stay here."

Comment: So, what could I ask about the etymology?

Comment: Nothing whatsover.

Comment: Look at all the questions under https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology.

Comment: I really need to ask some question on the name "Ångström".